# To Compare two Integer Arrays are equal Or Not

Tags: c++, arrays

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

bool equal_arr(int* arr, int* arr2, int m, int n)
{
    if (m != n)
    {
        return false;
    }
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    bool res = false;
    while (i < n)
    {
        if (arr[i] == arr2[j])
        {
            res = true;
            i++;
            j++;
        }
        else
        {
            i++;
            j++;
            res = false;
        }
        return res;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    int arr[5] = { 4, 4, 4, 4, 4 };
    int arr2[5] = { 4, 5, 2, 8, 6 };
    if (equal_arr(arr, arr2, 5, 5))
        cout << "true" << endl;
    else
        cout << "false";
    return 0;
}
```

the above code should print true or false while comparing between two arrays, but it gives a wrong output while at any occurance if both element between the arrays is same it returns true for some logical issues,in my sample testcase you can see it.

Comment: You're calling it with `m != n` so it returns `false` immediately.

Comment: Yes,because if the size is not equal,then it should return false immediately.

Comment: So it works as intended then?

Comment: Why are you saying the size of one array is 6 when both are clearly 5?

Comment: The test case you gave doesn't demonstrate your problem and your question is an incomprehensible run-on sentence.

Comment: @sniperr, don't get upset when someone is trying to help and asks for clarification. The way you formed your question really is not very clear, and the logic mistake is very basic.

Comment: i am  sorry,this is my first post.sorry if i disrespected anyone!

Comment: The function returns right after the `if ... else ...` code, so it only shows the result of comparing the first element of each array. The usual way to do this is to immediately `return false;` if two corresponding elements are not equal, and `return true;` if the loop runs through all the elements without seeing a mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is wrong. This

```
        if (arr[i] == arr2[j])
        {
            res = true;
            i++;
            j++;
        }
        else
        {
            i++;
            j++;
            res = false;
        }
```

would make your comparison function return the comparison of the last elements, because with each iteration you are overriding the previous result. And the `return` statement in the end of the loop makes it even less clear: you are always comparing only first element (because you return after the first iteration).

Better like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    if (arr[i] != arr2[i]) return false;
}
return true;
```

because just one pair of elements that are not equal is enough to return `false`.

Comment: Thanks !!it Worked..

Comment: but this logic wont work if there is a different element in the middle of a array,its completely depends on last pair of elements ..

Comment: Of course it will work for any kind of array, also empty array (considering 2 empty arrays are equal): https://godbolt.org/z/e9vMb4rn7